# When is $\log_{b}(a)$ irrational, for natural numbers $a,b$?

Tags: logarithms, rationality-testing

I've seen this result usually given as "if $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then $\log_{b}(a)$ is irrational." Wolfram|Alpha even says it is "unknown" whether or not $\log_{12}(6)$ is irrational, but I think it is easy to show this is irrational (unless I'm missing something obvious):

By way of contradiction, suppose $\dfrac{\ln(6)}{\ln(12)} = \dfrac{n}{m}$ with integers $n,m$. Without loss of generality, take $n,m$ to be natural numbers.

Then $m\ln(6) = n\ln(12)$. Hence, $6^{m} = 12^{n}$, so we have $2^{m}3^{m} = 2^{2n}3^{n}$, and so:

$2^{m-2n}3^{m} = 3^{n}$

Since $3^{n}$ is odd, so is $2^{m-2n}3^{m}$, therefore $m-2n = 0$, and $m = 2n$. Hence $\dfrac{\ln(6)}{\ln(12)} = \dfrac{1}{2}$. This is a contradiction, so $\dfrac{\ln(6)}{\ln(12)}$ is irrational.

This leads me to believe that $a,b$ being coprime is a sufficient condition to say that $\log_{b}(a)$ is irrational, but not a necessary one. My question is, can we give a stronger result regarding whether or not $\log_{b}(a)$ is irrational? Can we give a necessary and sufficient condition? Does anyone know of a specific example of $a,b$ where the irrationality of $\log_{b}(a)$ really is unknown?

Comment: You seem to be restricting yourself to $a,b$ being positive integers. In that case, it may not be difficult to provide an iff condition on the logarithm being irrational .

Answer (score 3):

The number $\log_b{a}$ is irrational iff no integer power of $a$ is an integer power of $b$. Indeed, if $a^m=b^n$ then $m\log_b a=n$, so $\log_b a=n/m$. Conversely, if $\log_b a=n/m$, then $\log_b a^m=n,$ so $b^n=a^m$.

For example for $a=6, b=12$, $a^m=b^n$ means $2^m3^m=2^{2n}3^n$ which is impossible.

**Remark** Note that if $a=p_1^{k_1}...p_s^{k_s},
b=p_1^{l_1}...p_s^{l_s}$ then $a^m=b^n$ means
$p_1^{mk_1}...p_s^{mk_s}=p_1^{nl_1}...p_s^{nl_s}$
or $mk_1=nl_1,...,mk_s=nl_s$. This implies that $k_i\ne 0$ iff $l_i\ne 0$ and all numbers $l_i/k_i$ are the same for every $i$ such that $k_i\ne 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The Gelfond-Schneider theorem answers this directly, and for a much broader class of numbers.  If $a, b > 0$ are algebraic numbers, and $b \neq 1$, then $\log_b a$ is either rational or transcendental.  The first case holds exactly when (as the other answer states) $a$ and $b$ have a common integer power.

Comment: Could we state this in terms of prime factorization? Maybe, they all have the same prime factors in the same proportions?

Comment: For integers, absolutely; just as you say.  Let $a=\prod p_i^a_i$ and $b=\prod p_i^b_i$, where $p_i$ ranges over all the primes and $a_i, b_i$ are integers $\ge 0$.  Then $\log_b a$ is rational iff $a_i$ and $b_i$ are nonzero for exactly the same values of $i$ and $a_i/b_i$ is a constant $c$ at those values.  (In which case, of course, $\log_b a = c$.)

Comment: Thank you, I looked at Gelfond-Schnieder as well. I have seen that theorem before (I did not remember the name), but I didn't even think to apply it here because we aren't looking at a number of that form. I see now that you are using its contrapositive. $b^{\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}} = a$. Since $a$ is not transcendental, it follows that $b^{\frac{\ln(a)}{\ln(b)}}$ is either not irrational or not algebraic. That is a really nice example of using a theorem's contrapositive.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when $a,b$ are both positive integers and $b \neq 1$, there is a relatively efficient algorithm to determine when $\log_b(a)$ is rational without having to consider prime factorization or possibly dealing with large powers:

(1) If $b \leq a$, then check whether $\frac{a}{b}$ is an integer:

- If so, then replace $a$ with $\frac{a}{b}$ and repeat step (1).
- If not, then stop, it's irrational.

(2) If $a=1$, then stop, it's rational.

(3) Swap $a$ and $b$ and go to step (1).

Additionally, if you keep track of the steps, you can easily get the continued fraction representation of the logarithm assuming it's rational.

The proof this algorithm is correct still uses the fundamental theorem of arithmetic as in your question and some of the other answers, but in application, all we need is to determine divisibility.

---

For instance, $\log_{12}(6)$ sets $b=12, a=6$, it goes something like (skipping the steps that don't do anything):

- Swap $a$ and $b$, so $a=12$ and $b=6$
- Set $a = 12/6 = 2$
- Swap $a$ and $b$, so $a=6$ and $b=2$
- Set $a=6/2 = 3$
- Since $b =2 \leq 3 = a$ but $3/2$ isn't an integer, $\log_{12}(6)$ is irrational.